# How to localize a Component in the SDL Tridion JS Framework (Anguilla) 2011?

Tags: 2011, cme

I want to localize a Component, and then edit some stuff in it.

```
function loadCompOnLocalize(e) {
  var localizedSeoComponent = e.source;
  if (localizedSeoComponent.isLocalized()) {//do stuff}
}

function loadCompOnLocalizeFailed(e) {//do other suff}

function seoComponentAfterLoad(component) {
  if (component.isLocalized()) {
    $log.debug("Component '{0}' is already localized.", childComponentId);
  } else {
    $evt.addEventHandler(component, "load", loadCompOnLocalize);
    $evt.addEventHandler(component, "loadfailed", loadCompOnLocalizeFailed);
    component.localize(true);
}

function seoComponentLoad(e) {
  $evt.removeEventHandler(e.source, "load", seoComponentLoad);
  $evt.removeEventHandler(e.source, "loadfailed", seoComponentLoadFailed);
  seoComponentAfterLoad(e.source);
};

function seoComponentLoadFailed(e) {
    $evt.removeEventHandler(e.source, "load", seoComponentLoad);
    $evt.removeEventHandler(e.source, "loadfailed", seoComponentLoadFailed);
    $log.debug("Failed to load seo component '{0}'", childComponentId);
};

if (childComponent.isLoaded()) {
  seoComponentAfterLoad(childComponent);
} else {
  $evt.addEventHandler(childComponent, "load", seoComponentLoad);
  $evt.addEventHandler(childComponent, "loadfailed", seoComponentLoadFailed);
  childComponent.load(true, $const.OpenMode.VIEW);
}
```

The problem is that when it enters `loadCompOnLocalize`, the Component returns false for `.isLocalized()`.

On the configuration side: I have the `Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Communicator` disabled in configuration (because is like this in production). If is enabled, it works fine, because when it enters the handler for "load", the Component it has the correct value for `isLocalized()`. But when is disabled, there is no way I can check when the Component finished to be localized.

Comment: What version is this? I just tried the same on my local instance and it worked fine...

Comment: Any chance you're accidentally checking isLocalizable instead of isLocalized? That would indeed return false if it's already localized...

Comment: no, I am checking isLocalized()

Comment: Maybe you could post the full code? Or at least the smallest amount of code you can reproduce the issue with. Also please tag it with the version you are using :)

Comment: I added the rest of the code involved in loading the component and also some configuration settings.

Comment: You missed an end curly brace ("}") for the else statement in seoComponentAfterLoad. But other than that, I see no issues with the code and it's working fine for me. Perhaps the problem is what the component you are using? Check that it's not checked out or localized or under workflow and that it's actually shared from a parent Publication.

Comment: Solved the problem like this:
1. Instead of loading the component to check if is localized, I used a sync call: tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.General.GetItem(childComponentId, $const.OpenMode.VIEW, onSuccess, onFail, null, true). This is returning an xml from the server.
2. onSuccess I checked the xml for the "tcm:IsLocalized" element and if true, localized the component with childComponent.localize(true);

Comment: That seems like a workaround that should not be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem with this workaround:

1. Instead of loading the component to check if is localized, I used a sync call: tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.General.GetItem(childComponentId, $const.OpenMode.VIEW, onSuccess, onFail, null, true). This is returning an xml from the server.
2. onSuccess I checked the xml for the "tcm:IsLocalized" element and if true, localized the component with childComponent.localize(true);–